# Entity Framework 6 Include from string Array

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, include, entity-framework-6

im trying to simplify includes statemens by callings methods from an string array:

```
Dim list As New List(Of User)
Using ctx As New UsersEntities
    Dim query = ctx.User
    For Each s As String In relations.Split(",") 'relations = "Role,Gender"
        If s IsNot Nothing And s.Length > 0 Then
            query.Include(s)
        End If
    Next
    list = query.ToList()
End Using
Return list
```

but, when list are returned, it throw an "System.ObjectDisposedException"

there anyway to do that?? I need to teel EF dynamically what "Relations" i want to include using a string separated by commas

PS: i tried disabling LazyLoad, but Relations returns Nothing always.

Thnks!!!

Comment: First, it should be `query = query.Include(s)`. Second, I think the error is not related to the includes, but you probably access a navigation property after the context is disposed.

Comment: I had not noticed that. So, I tried to add query = query.Include (s), but I'm getting a casting exception  (Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1 [User]' to type 'System.Data.Entity. DbSet`1 [User] '.)

Comment: I could solve the problem! You must specify the type of the variable "query" to Infraestructure.DBQuery, and also fix the sentence: query = query.Include (s). Thnks @GertArnold!!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

must specify the type of the variable "query" to Infraestructure.DBQuery, and also fix the sentence: query = query.Include (s)

```
Dim list as new List(Of User)
Using ctx As New UsersEntities
    Dim query As Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery(Of User) = ctx.User
    For Each s As String In relations.Split(",")
        If s IsNot Nothing And s.Length > 0 Then
            query = query.Include(s)
        End If
    Next
    list = query.ToList()
End Using
```